# Alternatives to Google Scholar, dblp to measure the scientific impact of a research article?

Tags: publications, google-scholar, bibliometrics

Are there any cross-platform websites to measure scientific impact of any research article? I am aware of dblp, Google Scholar and Microsoft Academic Search. Recently, ResearchGate is quite popular. However, all these are not optimal in several aspects.

For example, Google Scholar is a good platform for citation index, particularly h-index of any author; dblp is intended for most authentic, however lacks in the timely updating. ResearchGate seems to be updated mostly by individual scholars. I know that it is not possible to find a comprehensive database with authentic information contained. Thus, the criteria may be as follows: timely manner, self citation exclusion, information entered by authors or robot cross-checked by any person, and most importantly free access to scholars. (Scopus is not free.)

Comment: What are you asking for? A list of all the places that measure "scientific impact"?  And what does "highlight the issue" mean in this context?

Comment: Please clarify: Are you aware of any issues (list them! Define precisely what you expect of a measure of "scientific impact", because there probably is no globally accepted/useful definition.) and looking for an alternative that circumvents the issues, or are you unaware of any issues and want us to highlight them? (In case the answer is "both" - these are two different questions, so please ask them separately.)

Comment: @Mapper and EnergyNumbers, Hope now it is clear after edit. If you need any more information, please tell  me.

Comment: DBLP is fast at updates for the conferences and journals that matter. On the other hand, Google scholar is the de-facto standard for tracking citations. If most people use Google scholar, there is no need to expect it to be perfect but is good enough for most purposes.

Comment: @Alexandros: "Google scholar is the de-facto standard for tracking citations" - given the severe distortions in Google Scholar's h-index based upon the random inclusion of undergrad works, I have not yet met anyone who would have looked seriously at Google Scholar for determining the impact of someone or something - although opinions here on Academia SE seem to differ sometimes. Google Scholar is an excellent tool for finding related work, but the "statistics" tools like citation counts seem more like a well-intended, but failed feature.

Comment: You are asking for a golden goose, I am afraid. It seems unlikely that a business like that could survive, if the database is offered for free *and* someone needs to be paid to manually review all entries.

Comment: @Federico Poloni Regarding authenticity of the articles, there may be some way-out to solve. Like most of the reviewers are not paid even the journals are open-access or subscription-based. After all, it a task of scholar for the sake of academic. However, the journals do business. Now coming to the said database, there exist provisions for example, the subscribed institute can directly update the information contained without further delay made by external reviewers, at the end, we all want fast-updated database to track over increasing number of publications and obviously the authenticity.

Comment: I understand, and I agree with you that it would be a great system. Unfortunately, though, nothing similar exists at the moment (not that I know, at least). The closest match seems [Orcid](http://orcid.org/), which is a recent system backed up by a consortium of publishers and institutions. It is still preliminary, though, and it is still uncertain whether it will gain enough momentum to become a standard.

Comment: Microsoft Academic Search hasn't been updated since 2012.  it's dead.

Comment: _I have not yet met anyone who would have looked seriously at Google Scholar for determining the impact of someone or something_ — Hi, @O.R.Mapper.  Nice to meet you.

Comment: Biggest problem with Google Scholar is that it cannot distinguish works by authors with the same name.  Chinese authors exploit this to get high cites stats.

Comment: @Prof. Santa Claus, how could you say that? I think you ignore the fact that in Google Scholar, there is an update settings asking about either automatic updating or checked by author. Thus, it is not directly related to the Chinese, it may be anyone. And by the way, Chinese prefer their own Google Scholar alternative like xueshu.baidu.com

Comment: @Mithun because most Chinse Google profiles are not correct and authors do not bother cleaning up papers that don't belong to them, Chinese names are generally not unique and in the western world no one cares about the copy cat Baidu.

Comment: Again, you missed the point. Please see the comments by @Federico Poloni. For your clarification, Orcid and ResearcherID are now commonly used by some publishers to remove the ambiguity. Recently, I see that, for the final proof of an IEEE Journal, providing Orcid ID of the corresponding author is mandatory. If you still want to argue, please start a new post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled scientific research referencing websites and networks, and some links to further information, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160122195333/http://alfonsoycia.blogspot.com.es/2015/06/recursos-y-redes-sociales-para-la.html) (the post is in Spanish, with some automatic translation available).

Comment: When you post a link to your own blog, please disclose the affiliation and do not present it as a third party.

Comment: Thanks for the remark on the affiliation, but where did I present it as a third party?

Comment: Writing "here is this blog post" generically instead of "this is a post from my blog" in my view means failing to disclose your relationship and presenting it as a third party. Maybe not in lawyer's terms, but at least in spirit.

Comment: It could also be argued that, because I did not disclose the affiliation, I was presenting it as my own, if it was not. Spirit is hardly measurable. Anyway this discussion is off-topic.

Comment: @AlfonsoFR I do not see this discussion off-topic at all. In academic world is a must to cite work in a proper way, and honesty, i.e., clarity, with the information sources is best practice. Thus, consider rewording your answer "**I made** a compilation to scientific research referencing ..., here is **my post** ...". In that case your answer might deserve a full +1 ;)

Comment: I see your point now, thanks.

Comment: @AlfonsoFR quizas deberia incluid citeseer en tu lista?
(https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CiteSeerX)

Comment: I don't think CiteSeerX provides that kinds of metrics @J..yB..y

Answer (score 0):

[Semantic Scholar](https://semanticscholar.org/) is another option. It has an ["influential citation"](https://www.semanticscholar.org/faq#influential-citations) features that

> identifies citations where the cited publication has a significant impact on the citing publication, making it easier to understand how publications build upon and relate to each other. Influential citations are determined utilizing a machine-learning model analyzing a number of factors including the number of citations to a publication, and the surrounding context for each.

Its interface contains many useful information:

[image]